# ABS Menu Item not appearing in Android 2.3

Tags: android

I am implementing ABS within my application, and I have a FragmentPagerAdapter that allows the user to swipe/select different tabs.

Each of these tabs contains a different fragment. Basically, my problem is that on an Android 2.3.6 device that I'm testing with, when the activity is first called, the first tab-fragment doesn't inflate the menu it is supposed to. However, once I swipe to another tab and go back, it appears.

Here is the code within the fragment:

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater inflater = getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_ongoing_fragment, menu);
}
```

Meanwhile, it works completely fine on an Android 4.2 device (the menu is inflated the first time the activity is launched) Does it have something to do with the order in which these two devices are calling the methods?

Comment: Why are you using onPrepareOptionsMenu instead of OnCreateOptionMenu?

Comment: Because I first implemented it using OnCreateOptionMenu and that was where I discovered the problem, so I tried to switch it to see if there was a difference

Comment: Have you called `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`?

Comment: Yes, I set it when the fragments are added

Comment: I'd just like to emphasize that it works completely fine on 4.2, just for some reason doesn't appear the first time on 2.3.6 until you swipe to some other tab and go back

Comment: Then please try to add `super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)`

Comment: Where exactly you call setHasOptionsMenu? I think it must be called in onCreate method of the fragment.

Comment: @user1897423 I tried that before and it stays the same. To Cilenco: Oops, forgot about that I will try and report back

Comment: Yep adding super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu) didn't help..

Comment: Which ABS version are you using (see changelog here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)? The newest? Had a similar issue while using a `ViewPager` with ABS 4.0.2. Finally it turned out, that the result was based on a racing condition (see https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/351). So if none of above helps you, I can post my workaround - may be it will do.

Comment: Yes I am using the newest version of ABS, but anything that might fix the problem is welcome!

Comment: FWIW, here is a sample project that uses ActionBarSherlock and changes its action bar items based upon the visible fragment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/ActionBar It works correctly on a 2.3.3 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of this:

```
menu.clear();
```

Remove that.

You should have the following code on your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
};
```

and instead of "onPrepareOptionsMenu()" use this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_ongoing_fragment, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried this and it still hasn't solved my problem